# Archived file size exceeds the specified size, archiveAboveSize with NLog

Tags: nlog

I have the setting of NLog below:

```
<target name="asyncFile" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="10000" overflowAction="Block">
     <target xsi:type="File"
               fileName="/storage/sdcard0/com.my.app/Logs/${shortdate}.log"
               archiveFileName="/storage/sdcard0/com.my.app/Logs/archived.{#}.log"
               maxArchiveFiles="5"
               archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
               archiveAboveSize="1048576"
               archiveEvery="Day"
               archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
               concurrentWrites="true"
               keepFileOpen="false">
       <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" excludeProperties="Comma-separated list (string)">
         <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
         <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
         <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
         <attribute name="exception" layout="${exception}" />
         <attribute name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
       </layout>
     </target>
   </target>
```

Expected behaviours:
No more than 5 archived files are generated, and each has a maximum size of 1MB.

```
archived.1.log
archived.2.log
archived.3.log
archived.4.log
archived.5.log
```

Actual behaviours:
One archived file has more 40 MB

Any idea?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3661 (Issue on Xamarin Android Platform)

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3756 (Same question)

Answer (score 2):

Using `${shortdate}` in fileName is not supported together with `archiveFileName`.

```
fileName="/storage/sdcard0/com.my.app/Logs/${shortdate}.log"
```

Solution 1 (New style that works with NLog ver. 4.5 and newer)

```
    <target xsi:type="File"
           fileName="/storage/sdcard0/com.my.app/Logs/App.${shortdate}.log"
           maxArchiveFiles="5"
           archiveAboveSize="1048576"
           concurrentWrites="true"
           keepFileOpen="false">
```

Solution 2: (Remove `${shortdate}` from NLog so it works as intended):

```
 <target xsi:type="File"
           fileName="/storage/sdcard0/com.my.app/Logs/ActiveLog.log"
           archiveFileName="/storage/sdcard0/com.my.app/Logs/archived.{#}.log"
           maxArchiveFiles="5"
           archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
           archiveAboveSize="1048576"
           archiveEvery="Day"
           archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
           concurrentWrites="true"
           keepFileOpen="false">
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archive-old-log-files

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples